# I am curious about that where will the transaction fees go to finally?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, news-coverage, exchange-fees

Version 0.8.1's lowest fee is 0.0005.
Now the version 0.8.3's lowest fee is 0.0001.

1 million transaction would cost nearly 100 BTC.
They can't just disappear.
Where are they?

Answer (score 1):

Every transaction fee is paid to miners. So whichever miner discovers your block gets all of the fees for your transaction, plus whatever other transactions are included in that block.